# cannot run "create extension hstore" in postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-postgresql, hstore

I am trying to run db:migrate from my rails application.

migration file:

```
 def self.up
    enable_extension "hstore"
 end
 def self.down
    disable_extension "hstore"
 end
```

Error:

> -- enable_extension("hstore")
>   rake aborted!
>   StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
>
> PG::UndefinedFile: ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/pgsql-9.4/share/extension/hstore.control": No such file or directory
>   : CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "hstore"/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `async_exec'

```
postgres=# select version(); ==> PostgreSQL 9.4.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11), 64-bit
(1 row)
```

After searching relating to this issue, i found out 'hstore' dependency can be solved using postgresql-contrib. I added postgresql-contrib but no use still.

```
yum install postgresql ==> Package postgresql-8.4.20-2.el6_6.x86_64 already installed and latest version

yum install postgresql-contrib ==> Package postgresql-contrib-8.4.20-2.el6_6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

Comment: Those packages appear to be for Postgres 8.4. Try `yum install postgresql94-contrib`.

Comment: @NickBarnes, Pls post your comment as an answer. So that i can upvote. It really helped.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mess in PostgreSQL instances - active PostgreSQL is 9.4, installed rpm 8.4.

Answer (score 0):

Need to install 9.4 contrib e.g. `yum install postgresql94-contrib` and not `8.4`.